# Remove unwanted character in string using regex

Tags: php, regex, string, pattern-matching

I'm trying to remove characters that do not match a specific pattern using the example below:

Pattern to match exactly 4 alphabets `[a-zA-Z]{4}` followed by space(s) `\s{1,}` then 4 characters starting with an alphabet, last 3 number `[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{3}`

If I supply `ABEH A501; BIOL L340; BIOL Z620; Q799; ABEH A501` it matches all except `Q799`, now, I need to remove/replace `Q799` from the string.

I tried to apply [Negated Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) but still not getting the desired result.

```
$mystring = "ABEH A501; BIOL L340; BIOL Z620; Q799; ABEH A501";
$string = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]{4}\s{1,}[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{3}/","",$mystring);

echo $string; //ABEH A501; BIOL L340; BIOL Z; ABEH A501
```

The desired result should be `ABEH A501; BIOL L340; BIOL Z620; ABEH A501`

`Q799` was removed so also was part of another matching string, not sure if this was due to wrong regEx or wrong application of negated character class.

Comment: `\s{1,0}` what is that means?

Comment: Match at least one or more spaces?

Comment: Since many wrong variations of the pattern you want can occur, wouldn't it be better to extract the patterns that do match with `preg_match()`?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/KXhIWa/3 as per this your regex is invalid. Use + or {1,}. {1,0} makes no sense ("from 1 to 0 characters")

Comment: for at least one or more use `{1,}` or `+`
`{1,0}` I think this means from 1 to 0

Comment: Fixed regex, but still not getting the desired result.

Comment: you want get `ABEH A501; BIOL L340; BIOL Z620; ABEH A501` in result?

Comment: Yes.............

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP you can define a known good match regex and use PCRE verbs `(*SKIP)(*F)` to skip these matches in replacement:

```
$mystring = "ABEH A501; BIOL L340; BIOL Z620; Q799; ABEH A501";
echo preg_replace('/[a-zA-Z]{4}\s+[a-zA-Z]\d{3}(*SKIP)(*F)|\w+\W*/', '', $mystring);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/B2MWlR/3)

**Output:**

```
ABEH A501; BIOL L340; BIOL Z620; ABEH A501
```

[PHP Code Demo](https://ideone.com/l3Cs1C)

Comment: Any specific reason why you used `\s{1,8}` instead of `\s{1,0}`

Comment: Sorry it is fixed. I read `{1,0}` as `{1,8}`. It can simply be `\s+` as in my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

This is a different approach to the question, but hey, it works

```
<?php

$mystring = "ABEH A501; BIOL L340; BIOL Z620; Q799; ABEH A501";
preg_match_all("/[a-zA-Z]{4}\s{1,}[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{3};?\s+?/",$mystring, $matches);
$result = "";
foreach($matches[0] as $match) {
    $result = $result.$match;
}
echo $result; //ABEH A501; BIOL L340; BIOL Z620; 

?>
```